# Is it possible to get multiple values from a subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any way to have a subquery return multiple columns in oracle db? (I know this specific sql will result in an error, but it sums up what I want pretty well)

```
select
    a.x,
    ( select b.y, b.z from b where b.v = a.v),
from a
```

I want a result like this:

```
a.x | b.y | b.z
---------------
1   | 2   | 3
```

I know it is possible to solve this problem through joins, but that is not what I am asking for.

My Question is simply if there is any way, to get two or more values out of a subquery? Maybe some workaround using dual? So that there is NO actual join, but a new subquery for each row?

EDIT: This is a principle question. You can solve all these problems using join, I know. You do not need subqueries like this at all (not even for one column). But they are there. So can I use them in that way or is it simply impossible?

Comment: Why don't you want to use joins?

Comment: Can you not use a join on b.v = a.v and then you can easily get your fields.

Comment: I know it is not efficient but you could repeat the subquery per column you want in the output?

Comment: It's a performance thing, why I came to think about this, quite often subqueries are faster (at least when loading just a few records) depending on how the optimizer goes about things. Especially with user defined functions... BUT I'm asking a principle question (Also if you use joins, you do not need subqueries like this at all, and they are there, so why not get more than one value).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A Subquery in the Select clause, as in your case, is also known as a Scalar Subquery, which means that it's a form of expression. Meaning that it can only return one value.

I'm afraid you can't return multiple columns from a single Scalar Subquery, no.

Here's more about Oracle Scalar Subqueries:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions010.htm#i1033549

Answer (score 24):

It's incorrect, but you can try this instead:

```
select
    a.x,
    ( select b.y from b where b.v = a.v) as by,
    ( select b.z from b where b.v = a.v) as bz
from a
```

you can also use subquery in join

```
 select
        a.x,
        b.y,
        b.z
    from a
    left join (select y,z from b where ... ) b on b.v = a.v
```

or

```
   select
        a.x,
        b.y,
        b.z
    from a
    left join b on b.v = a.v
```

Comment: Simplified, no need for derived table there.

Comment: Yes, of course, but when OP wants to add more conditions to subquery?

Comment: Then, you can append those conditions at the `ON` clause.

Comment: Yes he can, but I leave query with subquery, maybe for OP it will useful.

Comment: Yes, it could be useful for others too (remove the second `join` though, after the parenthesis)

Answer (score 10):

Here are two methods to get more than 1 column in a scalar subquery (or inline subquery)  and querying the lookup table only once. This is a bit convoluted but can be the very efficient in some special cases.

1. You can use concatenation to get [several columns at once](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52586/2):

   ```
   SELECT x, 
          regexp_substr(yz, '[^^]+', 1, 1) y,
          regexp_substr(yz, '[^^]+', 1, 2) z
     FROM (SELECT a.x,
                  (SELECT b.y || '^' || b.z yz
                     FROM b
                    WHERE b.v = a.v)
                     yz
             FROM a)
   ```

   You would need to make sure that no column in the list contain the separator character.
2. You could also use [SQL objects](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54958/1):

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE b_obj AS OBJECT (y number, z number);

   SELECT x, 
          v.yz.y y,
          v.yz.z z
     FROM (SELECT a.x,
                  (SELECT b_obj(y, z) yz
                     FROM b
                    WHERE b.v = a.v)
                     yz
             FROM a) v
   ```

Comment: warning : concatenation do not work with null values !

Answer (score 4):

you can use `cross apply`:

```
select
    a.x,
    bb.y,
    bb.z
from
    a
    cross apply
    (   select b.y, b.z
        from b
        where b.v = a.v
    ) bb
```

If there will be no row from **b** to mach row from **a** then `cross apply` wont return row. If you need such a rows then use `outer apply`

If you need to find only one specific row for each of row from **a**, try:

```
    cross apply
    (   select top 1 b.y, b.z
        from b
        where b.v = a.v
        order by b.order
    ) bb
```

Comment: late to the party but this is nothing else than an inner join they just added this for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use JOIN like this one?

```
SELECT
a.x , b.y, b.z 
FROM a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.v = a.v
```

(I don't know Oracle Syntax. So I wrote SQL syntax)

Comment: Perhaps you should use a Left outer join.

Comment: For this specific problem I can use join, maybe for all problems like this. I am not asking for a solution to the problem, but if there is a way to do it with subqueries.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle query

```
select a.x
            ,(select b.y || ',' || b.z
                from   b
                where  b.v = a.v
                and    rownum = 1) as multple_columns
from   a
```

can be transformed to:

```
select a.x, b1.y, b1.z
from   a, b b1
where  b1.rowid = (
       select b.rowid
       from   b
       where  b.v = a.v
       and    rownum = 1
)
```

Is useful when we want to prevent duplication for  table A.
Similarly, we can increase the number of tables:

```
.... where (b1.rowid,c1.rowid) = (select b.rowid,c.rowid ....
```

Answer (score 1):

View this web:
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/multiplee-row-column-subqueries.php

Use example

```
select ord_num, agent_code, ord_date, ord_amount  
from orders  
where(agent_code, ord_amount) IN  
(SELECT agent_code, MIN(ord_amount)  
FROM orders   
GROUP BY agent_code);
```